# JS Declare Class & Instantiate For Singleton

Tags: javascript, class, singleton, instance, declare

I just realized you can declare and construct a new instance of a class using `new`. This feels really elegant for singleton usage. Is this valid? If so are there any downsides?

```js
var c = new class C {

    constructor () {
        this.foo = 'bar';
    }

}

console.log(c.foo);
console.log(c.constructor.name);
console.log(c.constructor.prototype);
```

**Edit**

```js
console.log(C); // Uncaught ReferenceError: C is not defined
```

Comment: You can not instantiate another `C` class. Console logging c gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: C is not defined`. Also my intention is to use this in a module `export default new class C` but that is beside the point.

Comment: Hmm, but isn't the issue here that you'd have to have some knowledge about whether `c` exists? The benefit of the singleton pattern is that you can write `new Thing()` and it'll either create the singleton instance or hand you the existing singleton instance.

Comment: Technically I can `console.log(new c.constructor());` to get a second instance.

Comment: @Nick it seems to me that a singleton should be a single instance of a class. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern. So if you can not reuse `C` then that might suffice as a singleton.

@Taplar does poke a hole in this since technically one could use the constructor to create another instance.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton gives good solution, if your project is so small. But the project is larger, more complicating. Then your singleton class will be chaotic. You can chase states in singleton hardly, strange variables which comes from somewhere increase day by day.

A good idea is dropping class and using functional way. Give arguments required to functions and pass the next functions recursively. Like this:

```
const main = () => {
  const setting = {...}
  const resultA = funcA(setting)
  funcB(setting, resultA)
  funcC(resultA)
}
```

This way helps to let us know what function need setting. For example, `funcA` and `funcB`  require `setting` but `funcC` doesn't. More ahead, DB instance or network resource include in this, you can control various effects in detail! Details are find out by "Dependency Injection".

Comment: This solution seems to be more of an opinion of class vs function regarding project design. Maybe you can clarify your view with a better example?